# How to remove old urls from google and replace with new one

Tags: google-search

I have urls like
http://www.example.com/post/tvb-hong-kong-watch-live-467/
Now I remove watch live from url and make new url like this
http://www.example.com/post/tvb-hong-kong-467/

But google index first url, I want to replace old url with new one.What is best way to remove old url and reindex new url in Google.
Is there any option in htacess or in rebot.txt so that I can block old urls?

Comment: Try with webmaster tools. But you need to get google do your work, you just can say google what to show :)

Comment: I used robots.txt to remove all old urls from google like this  http://www.zustream.com/robots.txt   . Is it ok? please let me know

Comment: Yes, that will help too.